# Maven Java heap space and GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, multithreading, macos, maven, garbage-collection

I am trying to build jar of a maven project using `mvn clean package` and `mvn clean install`. I am getting GC overhead limit exceeded and Java heap space error

```
[INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:5.1.2:bundle (default) @ <project_name> ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  02:16 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-05-09T11:32:59+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] GC overhead limit exceeded -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/OutOfMemoryError
```

I understand there are many answers related to this, but most of them say to add `-Xmx1024m` or similiar stuff to fix the issue. It does not work for me.

NOTE: There is no issue with the code because `mvn clean package` on this code is working on other systems (mac and windows both). And in my system `mvn clean package` is working for other projects as well.

What have I done?

1. Checked the code... it is working fine on other systems.
2. Reinstalled maven and tried using the bundled maven that comes with intelliJ
3. added `-Xmx4098m` and `export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2048M -Xms1024M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024M -XX:MetaspaceSize=1024M"` to .zshrc file
4. monitored the heap space using virtualVM and the current heap space is well below the max heap space (so I cannot see the reason why heap space is exceeding).
5. I also tried to update the version of the plugin `maven-bundle-plugin:3.5.0:bundle` to the latest.

[image: Heap Space graph]

[image: Metaspace graph]

Sometimes, I also get this heap dump.
Here's the heap dump: https://sharetext.me/96mz7nr5ll,
https://ideone.com/KKSEWY

Comment: Maybe you run Maven with `-X` and see if you find out what's going on?

Comment: First question which Maven version do you use? Second how many modules/test etc. does this project have? Als you are building a bundle via maven-bundle-plugin furthermore is this an OSGi project? Furthermore the links to the heap dump are not usable (forcing me to drop my add blocker etc.) Is this project some where available?

Comment: @khmarbaise please find the update link. I believe ideone won't ask you to drop your adbloacker. Version of maven is Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d). The project has a single module but has many dependencies. No the project is not available online as it a private project.

Comment: @JFabianMeier I tried that. There are a lot of debug messages and then heap space exceeds. No error message at all.

Comment: Silly question, bin in #3 you say you "added" the argument, but that command line already has an Xmx switch. Did you **add** the new one at the end or modify the existing one? I'm not sure how Java reacts if you specify Xmx twice.

Comment: if you are talking about "added -Xmx4098m and export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2048M -Xms1024M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024M -XX:MetaspaceSize=1024M" to .zshrc file " then I meant added them one after the other. basically modified the existing one. @JoachimSauer

Comment: First remove all configurations for java memory etc. second make a simple call on plain command line `mvn clean package` afterwards remove `maven-bundle-plugin`(if it's not an OSGi project) furthermore which JDK version are you running on ? Aparat from that all  can you please check to run `mvn clean test` ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I cannot actually modify the code since it is my organization's repository and same code is working on everyone else's system. I tried mvn clean test and it also gave same error.

Comment: Do you like to identify the problem? If you are not changing things to remove the things step by step you won't be able to identify the problem. That can easily being done on a branch...apart from that all those steps can be tested locally... Based on what you've written `mvn clean test` fails the same which means either a test(s) is causing the problem or other things.. Which versions of the plugins are you using (all plugins check them via log file) ... so next step: `mvn clean process-test-classes` ....